# WiFi issue with Intel Wireless 7265, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, hp, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

lately my wifi slow down a lot (down speed 0.60/1.50 Mbs), while few months ago was ok. My friend with a macbook doesn't experience the same problem, so i think the connection is fine (on his laptop 22/30 Mbs).
Also when i turn on my computer i have to manually click on "enable wifi", something that few months ago i didn't have to.

I've looked for solution on the web and askubuntu, also tried many answers but problem persist.

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"FASTWEB-1-jnrmAC1MY22j"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: D0:D4:12:F4:D2:D2   
      Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:9215   Missed beacon:0



sudo lshw -c network
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 50
   serial: 34:02:86:df:0f:11
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-93-generic firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:48 memory:b2000000-b2001fff


 ifconfig
 lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
      indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
      indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1 
      Byte RX:107590 (107.5 KB)  Byte TX:107590 (107.5 KB)

  wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 34:02:86:df:0f:11  
      indirizzo inet:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::3602:86ff:fedf:f11/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:32286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:33089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:31886302 (31.8 MB)  Byte TX:26421190 (26.4 MB)


lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 50)
```

My laptop is an HP Spectre x360 13-4007nl, runs Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in with a "me too!"  Not sure what it is. It's worse on 17.04